Issues with Image Handling and Form Submission in JavaScript Code
what is wrong with this when submitting?
I'm currently working on a library management website where the admin can add books through a form. I'm encountering several issues with image handling and form submission in my JavaScript code.
Here's a breakdown of the problems I'm facing:
Image Handling in Form:
I've implemented functionality to allow the user to upload an image for the book cover. The image is displayed in the form upon upload, but I'm unsure how to properly save the uploaded image along with the book information and use it in another webpage.
Form Submission:
I want to ensure that each book has a unique ID before adding it to the book list. If the entered ID matches any existing IDs in the book list, I want to prevent form submission and prompt the user to enter a new ID. Despite implementing this validation, I encountered a strange behavior where form submission was allowed even when the ID matched an existing one, but only when window.location.href was uncommented.
Here's a snippet of my JavaScript code:
// Image Handling
document.getElementById("upImg").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        const imgData = e.target.result;

        document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src", imgData);

        sessionStorage.setItem("uploadedImageData", imgData);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

// Form Submission
const addBookForm = document.getElementById('addBookForm');
if (addBookForm) {
    addBookForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const bookID = document.getElementById("bookID").value;
        const isBookIDExists = booksList.some(book => book.id === bookID);
        if (isBookIDExists) {
            alert("Book ID already exists. Please enter a new ID.");
        } else {
            // Book details retrieval
            const bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
            const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
            // Retrieve other book details similarly

            // Book creation
            const newBook = new Book(
                bookID,
                bookName,
                author,
                // Include other book details here
            );

            // Add book to the list
            booksList.push(newBook);

            // Inform user about book addition
            alert("Book added successfully!");

            // Redirect to allBooks.html after a slight delay
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = '../pages/allBooks.html';
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

Could you please assist me in resolving these issues? I'm particularly concerned about properly saving the uploaded image with the book information and ensuring accurate form submission validation. Thank you.
Additional Information:
This is only the frontend part of the application; backend integration will be handled later.
The Book class and booksList are imported from another module.
The Book object contains properties such as id, name, author, etc.
The booksList array holds instances of Book objects representing all books in the library.
`
